# What should the main entry point be for a front end project?

Tags: npm, workflow, frontend, package.json

I was assigned a front-end project, [please find the description here](https://gist.github.com/nsbraksa/8de252884bc2c4f219887b9a7fa6072c)

The main task is to convert a mockup design to a responsive web page, with the use of gulp and sass. So I installed **node** and **npm** and **sass**, and I'm now trying to create my package.json file in my project directory on my PC, there were some questions that I need to answer in order to do that, like "project name", version, author ... and the **main entry point** for my project, that's the confusing part, because most tutorials I came across tell me to use **something.js** as the entry point, but considering my project, it will be mainly HTML and CSS and some JS if necessary so I don't see how this project can be initiated from a js file rather than **index.html** which seems IMO to be the right entry point! I want the opinion of experts about this and why would you choose what you chose. Thank you very much

Comment: @KenWhite I was told to make use of Gulp and Sass, So I used node to install gulp! can you please look at the mockup provided in the link and see what js work is needed in this project. Thanks

Comment: Okay, but I think the main use of Gulp is to compile Sass. Thank you for your help anyway!